# Helping understanding RedCode

Tags: assembly, corewars, redcode

I'm trying to learn redcode, because it looks fun to make a bot.

### Introduction

For those who don't know what redcode is, here's a short explanation.
It's an ASM-like language, but far more easy and stripped. It is used to write little programs that need to shut down other programs in virtual memory. (See for more info here: http://vyznev.net/corewar/guide.html)

Here's a piece of code:

```
;redcode
;name Mice
;author Chip Wendell
;strategy paper (replicator)
;history Winner of the 1986 ICWS tournament
Top dat #0, #0
Start   mov #12,    Top
Loop    mov @Top,   <Target
    djn Loop,   Top
    spl @Target,0
Spacer  equ 653
    add #Spacer,Target
    jmz Start,  Top
Target  dat #0, #833
    end Start
```

### Problem

The basic strategy is to replicate itself to another place, and the fork the process.
What I don't understand is this rule:

```
Loop    mov @Top,   <Target
```

I understand the meaning of this line. It says, move the B-Field of target to the line where the B-Field of top points, and decrease the value of the B-Field of target.

When loop is executed for the first time, the first line will be:

```
Top dat #0, #12
```

As far as I get, the line with Loop means:
Move the instruction 12 lines ahead (filled with dat #0, #0) to line 833.

But when this code is executed, the line of code is placed at line 839.

Does someone understand what is happening really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, that took quite a bit of reading, but here's your answer:

The first instruction, as you correctly surmise, makes Top into DAT #0, #12.  Simple enough, but the next instruction is trickier.  First, it decrements the B-value of Target (making it 832).  Then, it copies the instruction at Top into the location 832 lines ahead *relative to Target*.  That's the key: the indirect addressing mode means the destination is relative to the B-value read for the offset.  Now look at the code after compilation, with line numbers in front:

```
0000 Top    DAT.F  #0        #0       
0001 Start  MOV.AB #12       $-1      
0002 Loop   MOV.I  @-2       <5       
0003        DJN.B  $-1       $-3      
0004        SPL.B  @3        $0       
0005        ADD.AB #653      $2       
0006        JMZ.B  $-5       $-6      
0007 Target DAT.F  #0        #833
```

As you can see, Target is on line 7, so 832 lines ahead relative to Target is line 839.

Hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: Thx for the explenation. Someone else helped me allready, but thx anyway, it's clear now.